# Scons: How do you assign a Decider to a specific node?

Tags: scons

I have tried this:

```
p = env.Program("foo", source);
p[0].Decider('timestamp-match')
```

But this fails to accomplish the switch to using timestamps for that node, additionally, it leads to a subsequent builder that uses p as input to emit an error: TypeError : 'str' object is not callable

Comment: How do you known that this is possible at all? Can you point to a snippet in the docs (UserGuide, MAN page) stating that a `Decider` can be set for a single target?

Comment: I looked at the source code, a Node object has a Decider method(). 
https://scons.org/doc/latest/HTML/scons-api/SCons.Node-pysrc.html#Node.Decider

I also saw it as a unit test case: https://github.com/SCons/scons/blob/master/test/Decider/Node.py

Comment: How then do you use different Deciders throughout the codebase? I have a sitution where I need to use timestamp-match, but generally prefer md5 for most everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly assign a new `Decider` to a specific `Node`. The method `Node.Decider()` that you mentioned in your comment above, serves a different purpose (intended more for internal use*).

The key to a solution is that you can assign a `Decider` to an `Environment`. So, you only have to `clone` your default Environment and create the special target within it, using the timestamp decider. All other target nodes should use the `env` Environment as before. Untested, and from the top of my head...just to give you an idea:

```
env = Environment()
env_time = env.Clone()
env_time.Decider('timestamp')
# Use timestamps
env_time.Program('main', 'main.cpp')
# All other stuff, using MD5
env.XYZ()
```

(*) Yes, this raises the question why it's listed in the official API then, but that's a discussion for another day...on the SCons User Mailing List preferably. ;)

Comment: Thanks. However, that posed a problem in that I need ALL SConscripts to first load, as each sconscript is adding to the environment's dictionary, so if I Clone before all SConscripts have been read, I will get error in that the Cloned environment is incomplete. Perhaps there is a solution for that?

Comment: I don't understand why this is suddenly a problem now. If the order of your commands is basically the same as before, then the "cloned" Environment will be in exactly the same state as the default one, except that it uses "timestamps" now. Please tell us more details about why you think that **all** SConscripts have to be loaded first. What is the error message that you are currently seeing when trying to run the build? What is missing from the original Environment in your view?

Comment: We have a hierarchical build. So each SConscript that is loaded may add to some dictionary that are in the main construction environment. We have found this useful for recording library dependency that one library has on others. Then a program just has to refer to the libraries it has direct dependencies on, and any of their dependencies are also linked in. We accomplish this using a dictionary in the construction environment, but for it to work, all SConscripts must first be loaded, otherwise, it is incomplete say at the point of Cloning.

Comment: But since you stated that there is only one single target using the "timestamp" decider you don't have to load **all** SConstruct in advance. You only need the libraries as dependencies for the single target to be complete, correct? The other option that I can think of, would be to move the single "timestamp" target into its own little SConstruct file. Then you could include this as the last one from the top level.